# my MVC3/EF6 Webapi throwing intermittent 500 errors, possible database connection issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I have an (inherited from previous coder) ASP.NET MVC3 webapi that utilises Entity Framework(6.1.3) and I'm not convinced it is performing correctly. Mostly through seeming lack of the USING method.

**The Problem**

The reason I don't think it is performing correctly is because this put Method gets called a lot (via a scheduled task on various external servers). and quite often an `id` will return a `500 internal server error`. and then will run again and process correctly the next time the scheduled task is run.

**The Code**

The Controller `MyApiController` is as follows :

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    static readonly IMyApiRepository myApiRepository = new MyApiRepository();

    public HttpResponseMessage PutData(int id, int id2)
    {
        if(!myApiRespository.Update(id, id2))
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Error:Unable to Update");
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the Repository `MyApiRepository` is as follows

```
public class MyApiRepository : IMyApiRepository
{
    MyDBContext myContext;

    public MyApiRepository()
    {
        myContext = new MyDBContext();
    }

    public bool Update(int id,int id2)
    {
        var myData = myContext.MyData.Where(x => x.id == id);
        if (myData.Count() > 0)
        {
            MyData temp = myData.SingleOrDefault();
            temp.Processed = true;
            myContext.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like to me that the Database connection is permanently open, and that too many things are trying to use it all at once.

Should the `ApiRepository` constructor actually be empty

```
public MyApiRepository()
{

}
```

and the `Put` Method be

```
using (var myContext = new MyDBContext())
{
    var myData = myContext.MyData.Where(x => x.id == id);
    if (myData.Count() > 0)
    {
        //blah;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

thereby opening a single connection per request?

Comment: First step - you could wrap that `Update` method in a `try/catch` to grab any exceptions and report those back in the response of `MyApiController`. You'll be able to see more detail of what is going on